# Loop through array of objects to find object with matching property

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have 1 array, one with a list of all my users with unique IDs. I have an object which contains contains a selected groups information. Part of that information is the owners ID. I'm trying to figure out, how do I get the users's information given the groups owner ID? For example, the student group object has an owner ID of 70, there's a user on my sites who's ID is 70...how do I match them up?

```
users: 
[  { 
id: 68
name: mike
domain: i:0#.f|admembers|mike.ca
email: mike.ca
isAdmin: False
 }, etc etc ]

selectedGroup:  { 
name: Students
id: 78
description: 
owner: 70
ownerIsUser: True
 }
```

Comment: see [deepdash](https://github.com/YuriGor/deepdash)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You'll have to loop through `users`:

```
var i = users.length,
    ownerData;

while(i--) {
    if(selectedGroup.owner == users[i].id) {
        ownerData = users[i];
        break;
    }
}
```

Or you could use [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var ownerData = users.filter(function(user) {
    return user.id === selectedGroup.owner;
})[0];
```

Comment: var i = users.length, ownerData;   I've never seen anything like this before. What is "i" here?

Comment: It's a quick way of looping through an array--`i` is initialized to the length of your `users` array, and it is decremented in the while loop below. When `i` reaches 0, the loop executes a final time and ends. It loops through the array in reverse.

Comment: I understand the index part, just not the ownerData part. Shouldn't it be declared separately like var i = x.length; var ownerData;

Comment: Oh. I'm using a comma to separate statements, thus removing the need to place them on individual lines (the whitespace is just for readability). It cuts down on the character count, and is a fairly standard way to declare multiple variables.

Comment: Oh I didn't know I could do it like that. Well I knew I could declare multiple empty variables like this var a,b,c,d; but had no clue I could initialize their values too. Cool, thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 11):

In ECMAScript 6, you could use the native [`Array.find` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
var selectedUser = users.find( function( user ){
  return user.id === 70;
} );
```

Seeing as only the latest Firefox supports this for the moment, you could use a library like [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#find):

```
var selectedUser = _.find( users, function( user ){
  return user.id === 70;
} );
```

…or you could use a wrapper around the slightly less recent [`forEach` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
var selectedUser;

users.forEach( function( user ){
  if( user.id === 70 ){
    selectedUser = user;
  }
} );
```

But if you want to use script that'll support legacy browsers without using libraries, you'll need a for loop:

```
var selectedUser;

for( var i = 0; i < users.length; i++ ){
  if( users[ i ].id === 70 ){
    selectedUser = users[ i ];

    break;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#findWhere) to trivialize this, like so:

```
_.findWhere(users, { id: 68 })
```

Naturally you could pass in a variable to match like:

```
_.findWhere(users, { id: selectedGroup.owner })
```

Comment: Bad form to include a library for one utility function. Maybe take a look at Underscore's implementation of `findWhere` and copy it out.

Comment: I would have suggested having a broader look at the Underscore library as a comment, as it is likely there is more to be gained, but I am not yet able to comment on questions.

Answer (score 1):

You could just loop over the array to match that:

```
var match = function (array, matchfn) {
    var i;
    for (i in array) {
        if (matchfn(array[i])) {
            return array[i];
        }
    }
};

var user = match(users, function (u) { return u.id == 70; });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have to work with existing javascript objects, I think a brute-force solution is the only option:

```
var owner;
for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    if (users[i].id == selectedGroup.id) {
        owner = users[i];
        break;
    }        
}

if (owner) {
    console.log(owner);
}
```

Depending on how you use it, it may be more efficient to restructure your first object so you can directly access a property:

```
var users = {
    "68": {
        id: 68,
        name: 'mike',
        domain: 'i: 0#.f | admembers | mike.ca',
        email: 'mike.ca',
        isAdmin: false
    }
};

var selectedGroup = {
    name: 'Students',
    id: 78,
    description: '',
    owner: 68,
    ownerIsUser: 'True'
};

var owner = users[selectedGroup.owner];
```

Comment: Holy crap...I really like the idea of restructuring the array into objects. It would probably require I rewrite my services but it might make things simpler later on.

Comment: I'm trying to restructure the object has selected but I'm not sure how  to create a new properties from the loop. This is what I tried: http://jsfiddle.net/pGsc6/

Answer (score -1):

You can also use Array.prototype.some to compare all of the objects properties to see if they contain equal values.

```
function haveSameValues(oneObject, anotherObject) {
  var hasDifferentKeyValues = Object.keys(oneObject).some(function(key){ 
    return oneObject[key] !== anotherObject[key]
  });

  return !hasDifferentKeyValues;
}
```